# Where/how can I host my small, database-driven, Sinatra-powered Ruby app? Heroku limits database connections

Tags: ruby, database, heroku, hosting, sinatra

Here is my app: a [price inflation calculator](http://tranquil-peak-3911.herokuapp.com/). If you click 'Calculate,' you'll probably get a server-related error. When I tested the app out in Sinatra, I got an error saying

```
PG::Error: FATAL: too many connections for role "********"
```

After looking into it, it turns out that [Heroku limits its free databases to 20 connections](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-starter-tier#limits).

I'd like to continue developing small apps (especially database-driven ones) on Heroku, but I may not be able to if I'm unable to get around this restriction. I would pay $50/month to get a database that allows more connections, but I do not yet know if it would be worth it.

My question is: Does anyone know if it's possible to get around this restriction for free, or if there are alternatives to Heroku that can host a database-driven Sinatra app?

Here's the code I use that adds inflation data to the database:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rest-client'
require 'nokogiri'
require 'sequel'

### MAKE CPI DATABASE ###
db_name = 'DATABASE_NAME_HERE'
DB = Sequel.postgres(db_name,:user=>'USER_NAME',:password=>'PASSWORD',:host=>'HOST',:port=>5432,:sslmode=>'require')
    DB.create_table! :cpi_nsa_annual do
        primary_key :id
        Integer :year
        Float :cpi
    end # DONE: DB.create_table :cpi_nsa_annual do
cpi_annual = DB[:cpi_nsa_annual]
### DONE MAKING CPI DATABASE ###

post_url = "http://data.bls.gov/pdq/SurveyOutputServlet"

post_params = {
    'delimiter'=>'comma',
    'output_format'=>'html',
    'output_type'=>'column',
    'periods_option'=>'all_periods',
    'series_id'=>'CUUR0000SA0',
    'years_option'=>'all_years'
}

if page = RestClient.post(post_url,post_params)
    npage = Nokogiri::HTML(page)
    data = npage.css('table.regular-data tbody tr')

    data.each{|row|
        month_prefix = (row.css('th')[2].text)[0]
        year = row.css('th')[1].text
        month = (row.css('th')[2].text)[1..2]
        cpi = row.css('td').text

        if month_prefix=='M' and month=='13'
                cpi_annual.insert(
                    :year=>year,
                    :cpi=>cpi
                ) # DONE: cpi_annual_insert
                p ["YEAR",year,cpi]
        end # DONE: month_prefix=='M' and month!='13'
    }
end # DONE: if page
p cpi_annual.each{|row| p row}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

meub's answer suggesting you store the data outside of a database is sound, but if you feel like you really want to stick with a database try looking into why your app is using so many connections.

If you run `select * from pg_stat_database WHERE datname = 'yourdbname'` the 'numbackends' field will tell you how many connections are being made to your database. If you do a fresh deploy to heroku and then visit your app a few times does the number of connections increase? Perhaps you need to close your connection.

If you add `DB[:cpi_nsa_annual].disconnect` at the end of your code does the number of connections stop going up with each page load?

Comment: D'oh! Of course! Yeah, adding DB.disconnect seems to solve the problem. I added the code to the database-modifying script as well as the Sinatra. I used an "after do" statement for the Sinatra one (ie "after do DB.disconnect end")

Comment: @user1626730 Excellent! Glad it worked :) using `after do` sounds like the way to go.

Comment: @user1626730 Remember to upvote questions and answers that you find useful - this helps Stack Overflow keep the most helpful content at the top.

Answer (score 2):

It really doesn't seem like you need a database to accomplish what you want in that app. Can't you just store the annual rates in an array in your ruby code?

```
$inflation_rates = {"1999" => 2.19, "2000" => 2.97, "2001" => 3.73}
```

Or maybe I'm misunderstanding how your app works.

I've hosted small Sinatra apps with databases on Heroku without problems. The 20 connection limit has been enough. Are you sure its not a fault of your app? Maybe its using an excessive number of connections? Could you post your code?

Also, [OpenKeyVal](http://openkeyval.org/) is an awesome free key/value data store with no connection limit (the only limit is the key must be under 64KB). It might force you to change your code around but its at least worth looking into. Because you can store data with JSONP calls you can build an app that uses the datastore in a single static html file.

Comment: You know, shortly after I posted this I started thinking about doing a hash-key system, since annual inflation data is pretty slow to update. That would work for now, though I was hoping to add more data later on, and that *might* require something bigger, faster, and more flexible than a hash-key...Anyway, sorry for forgetting to post the code. I'll edit my post to include it.

Comment: You could also store the data as JSON or CSV and load that (given the data is static). Albeit Ruby code probably loads fastest. Just depends on what you need to do to balance ease of update vs volume of data.